# Adding data to Magento grid collection destroys pager

Tags: php, collections, magento, grid, pagination

in my own Magento Extension I'm using a grid block, to display the collection of data in my db table. Everything works fine so far and the standard pagination from magento works, too.

I now want to add some random data, which isn't in the db table, to the collection to show it in my grid. If I try as follow the pagination stops working:

```
class My_own_Block_Admin_Main_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    protected function _prepareCollection {

         // Load the collection
         $collection = getResourceModel('sales/order_grid_collection');

         // Add custom data
         $collection->addToAll('example', 'This is a test');

         // Set the collection
         $this->setCollection($collection);
         return parent::_prepareCollection();   
    }
}
```

The pagination is effectless now. Page 1 is the same as 2 and shows all entries.

What's the right and working way to a data to the collection without breaking the pagination?

Comment: http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Page/Mage_Page_Block_Html_Pager.html#_initFrame perhaps the pager needs to realize the change in the collection you've added in the stack?

Comment: You should accept your answer (the checkbox next to the score will do it), rather than marking the question as "solved"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to that is prolem is the following thread

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/192232/#t239222

Comment: Also, if the solution is easy, can you post it here so that it's easier to locate for searchers? :)